# How to pass array object in the onResponse function of Acitivity to Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I want pass array object `cauHoiArrayList` in `onResponse` function of Activity to Fragment. I tried many ways but failed, I'm always getting a null object. Here is my code:

```
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
                        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                            _id = object.getInt("_ID");
                            cauhoi = object.getString("CauHoi");
                            tenmh = object.getString("TenMH");
                            tenmonhoc = object.getString("TenMonHoc");
                            dapan_a = object.getString("DapAn_A");
                            dapan_b = object.getString("DapAn_B");
                            dapan_c = object.getString("DapAn_C");
                            dapan_d = object.getString("DapAn_D");
                            dapandung = object.getString("DapAnDung");
                            hinhanh = object.getString("HinhAnh");
                            dokho = object.getInt("DoKho");
                            cauHoiArrayList.add(new CauHoi(_id, cauhoi, tenmh, tenmonhoc, dapan_a, dapan_b, dapan_c, dapan_d, dapandung, hinhanh, dokho, ""));
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("laytenmonhocc", "" + laytenmonhoc);
            params.put("laydokhoc", "" + laydokho);
            return params;
        }
    };
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Comment: where are you calling this function from ?

Comment: When is this `onResponse` function gets called ? asynchronously or you call it explicitly ?

Comment: I edited my code. It's in onCreate function @NiamatullahBakhshi

Comment: I called it explicitly @Sam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your model class `CauHoi` should `implements` `Parcelable`, Then create a `fragment transaction` in your activity with `arraylist` as `arguments`

```
            YourFragment fragment=new YourFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();  
            bundle.putParcelableArrayList("arraylist", cauHoiArrayList);
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment,"myfrag");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Now get this arraylist data inside fragment like this

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
if (bundle != null) {  
ArrayList<CauHoi> cauHoiArrayList= bundle.getParcelableArrayList("arraylist");
}
```

Comment: thanks for your comment. But I can not use `Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();` in Fragment. My Activity and My Fragment is ViewPage. I also tried `Bundle e = getArguments();` but it did not work! @ヅfix

Comment: @VănTấn you can use `this.getArguments()` please see updated answer

Comment: I really want to thank you. Your way helped me. But I am so sorry, I am not enough reputation to upvote for you! @ヅfix

Comment: glad to hear it helped! ヅヅ